# NPM hangs and gets stuck on publish/pack

Tags: npm

npm publish and npm pack were both stuck for me. On the prepack step it would run indefinitely maxing out the CPU.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm posting this because I couldn't find the solution anywhere and I hope this helps someone else.

For me it was caused by using the Bit packager. Deleting .git/bit fixed the issue. If you don't have bit look for another package.json file and remove it.

Answer (score 3):

I got the same issue. The reason was that I had larges files of data (decades of Go) making packaging so slow that it looked to be stucked.

Comment: Had the same issue, i had lots of large 'junk' files in the folder and it caused the command to crash

Answer (score 2):

For me it was the registry that had issues. Make sure that everything is green at https://status.npmjs.org/!

Comment: Ended up being my (private) registry going unresponsive.  Even with `--verbose`, it just gets down to `total files: XYZ` then the next line stops and only responds to CTRL-C.

Comment: @Coderer,
We are facing the same issue. Have you resolved it? Please let us know the fix.

Comment: Sorry, when I say "my" private registry, I mean the private registry that I'm *using* -- I don't know what went wrong with it, or how they fixed it.  Once the registry came back up, `npm publish` worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered an issue while trying to publish with Npm, as the process seemed to be hung up and unresponsive. After several hours of troubleshooting, I discovered that the problem was being caused by the watch mode being enabled in the webpack.config.json file with the configuration of 'watch: true'. Once I removed this configuration, the publishing process completed successfully without any further issues.[image]

Answer (score 1):

For me the solution was

1. push project to remote repo
2. remove project locally
3. clone project from remote repo
4. npm publish // <- works here